# Solving several inequalities in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I am a very beginner of Mathematica and the following will probably be a very stupid question. I have a bunch of inequalities in 6 unknowns and I want to find the set of values satisfying them. Can I do it in Mathematica? I have tried using the command `Reduce`:

```
    =Reduce[{0 < -a - d + 1 < 1 , 0 < (2a + 2b + 2d - 3e + 2f + 1)/3 < 1 , 

    0 < -f - b + 1 < 1 , 0 < e < 1 , 0 < a < 1 , 

    0 < -(2f - 3e + 2d + 3c + 2b + 2a - 2)/3 < 1 ,  

    0 < f < 1 , 0 < (-3e + 2d + 3c + 2b + 1)/3 < 1 , 0 < d < 1 , 0 < c < 1 , 

    0 < b < 1 , 0 < -(2d + 3c + 2b - 2)/3 < 1}, a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

I get as Output some Definitions

```
1   verb    cut down on; make a reduction in
2   verb    make less complex
3   verb    bring to humbler or weaker state or condition
4   verb    simplify the form of a mathematical equation of expression by substituting one term for another
5   verb    lower in grade or rank or force somebody into an undignified situation
6   verb    be the essential element
7   verb    reduce in size; reduce physically
8   verb    lessen and make more modest
```

Is the number of inequalities too high? If I reduce the number of inequalities and run for example

```
 =Reduce[{0 < -a - d + 1 < 1 , 0 < (2a + 2b + 2d - 3e + 2f + 1)/3 < 1 , 

        0 < -f - b + 1 < 1 , 0 < e < 1 , 0 < a < 1}, a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

it works with output

```
b \[Element] Reals && 
 0 < a < 1 && -a < d < 
  1 - a && ((0 < e <= 1/3 (2 a + 2 d) && -b < f < 
      1/2 (2 - 2 a - 2 b - 2 d + 3 e)) || (1/3 (2 a + 2 d) < e <= 
      1/3 (1 + 2 a + 2 d) && -b < f < 1 - b) || (1/3 (1 + 2 a + 2 d) <
       e < 1 && 1/2 (-1 - 2 a - 2 b - 2 d + 3 e) < f < 1 - b))
```

Could you help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 1) By entering an `=` at the beginning of an expression (which will turn orange) you get wolfram alpha results, which in this case appear to be nonsense.  2)   For mathematica results your syntax is wrong, you need `{ }` around the variable list.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hence, what should I type in the Notebook to solve the system of inequalities above?

Comment: `FindInstance` quickly finds one instance satisfying your full system, which tells us it is properly posed.

Comment: But I want to find the whole set of solutions

Comment: Could you help me to understand why the way in which I put the command gives me that unreasonable answer? If I reduce the number of inequalities it works

Comment: Ok: I was using = because by pressing enter Mathematica was giving me the output. How can I get the output without = at the beginning? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: To make sure a user is notified when you reply to a comment, use @user (e.g. @MichaelE2).  Note that authors of posts are always notified when someone comments on their posts.

Comment: All I can say about the two different `=Reduce[...]` commands is that a natural language interpret uses heuristics to guess what is most important.  It seems to go different ways on the two inputs.

Comment: shift-enter to evaluate

Answer (score 2):

```
FindInstance[{
  0 < -a - d + 1 < 1,
  0 < (2 a + 2 b + 2 d - 3 e + 2 f + 1)/3 < 1, 0 < -f - b + 1 < 1,
  0 < e < 1,
  0 < a < 1,
  0 < -(2 f - 3 e + 2 d + 3 c + 2 b + 2 a - 2)/3 < 1,
  0 < f < 1,
  0 < (-3 e + 2 d + 3 c + 2 b + 1)/3 < 1,
  0 < d < 1,
  0 < c < 1,
  0 < b < 1,
  0 < -(2 d + 3 c + 2 b - 2)/3 < 1
  }, {a, b, c, d, e, f}]
```

> {{a -> 1/4, b -> 1/8, c -> 1/6, d -> 1/2, e -> 2/3, f -> 3/8}}

Note if i ask `FindInstance` to find two instances it does not return in time to suit my patience. (perhaps the result is the only solution) `Reduce` has the same syntax, but you probably want to specify the domain `Reals`:

```
FindInstance[{
     0 < -a - d + 1 < 1,...
      }, {a, b, c, d, e, f},Reals]
```

This also does not return quickly for me, but It might be worth your while to let it go a couple of hours.

Edit: `Reduce` did eventually return (maybe 5 minutes). It gives about 10 pages of conditions..(have fun using that result! )

Comment: This problem seems to be simply a Fourier-Moskin one. There exist also a package to resolve it  http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7034/

Answer (score 2):

```
region = Reduce[{0 < -a - d + 1 < 1, 
  0 < (2 a + 2 b + 2 d - 3 e + 2 f + 1)/3 < 1, 0 < -f - b + 1 < 1, 
  0 < e < 1, 0 < a < 1, 
  0 < -(2 f - 3 e + 2 d + 3 c + 2 b + 2 a - 2)/3 < 1, 0 < f < 1, 
  0 < (-3 e + 2 d + 3 c + 2 b + 1)/3 < 1, 0 < d < 1, 0 < c < 1, 
  0 < b < 1, 0 < -(2 d + 3 c + 2 b - 2)/3 < 1},
 {a, b, c, d, e, f}];.
```

It's really long.  Here's a look at the top few levels (the `<<2>>` etc indicate omitted parts of the expression):

```
Shallow[region, 5]
```

[image]